# Concise way to express commutators of two-qubit quantum gates

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer

I would like to calculate the commutator of quantum operations

- $C^{(ij)}$ (by that I mean CNOT with $i$ being the control qubit and $j$ being the target qubit; please correct me if there's a better and more common notation) single qubit operations, $\sigma_{x,y,z}^{(i)}$

and

- single qubit operations, $\sigma_{x,y,z}^{(i)}$ and  $\sigma_{x,y,z}^{(j)}$. So far, I have not come up with anything better than doing this in a brute force way, by multiplying $4\times4$ matrices and then decomposing them. I'm wondering if anyone could check my results or, even better, suggest a more appropriate way to approach the problem.

Conventions:
$$
C^{(12)}=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&1&0
\\\end{pmatrix}
\quad,\quad
\sigma^{(1)}_{x,y,z}=\sigma_{x,y,z}\otimes\hat{1}
\quad,\quad
\sigma^{(2)}_{x,y,z}=\hat{1}\otimes\sigma_{x,y,z}
\quad.
$$
Results so far:
$$
\begin{alignedat}{99}
&[C^{(12)},\sigma^1_x]  = - i \sigma_y\otimes(\hat{1}-\sigma_x)
\quad&&,\quad
[C^{(12)},\sigma^1_y]  = - i \sigma_y\otimes(\hat{1}-\sigma_x)
\quad&&,\quad
[C^{(12)},\sigma^{(1)}_z]  = 0
\quad&&,\\
&[C^{(12)},\sigma^{(2)}_x]  = 0
\quad&&,\quad
[C^{(12)},\sigma^{(2)}_y]  = -i(1-\sigma_z)\otimes\sigma_z
\quad&&,\quad
[C^{(12)},\sigma^{(3)}_z]  = i(1-\sigma_z)\otimes\sigma_y
\quad&&.
\end{alignedat}
$$
(too ugly to be true...)

It would be great to know if there's a more appealing and universal expression for the commutator between $\sigma^{i,j}_{x,y,z}$ and their controlled versions.

Comment: Can you use something like  $[A \otimes B, C \otimes D] = [A, C] \otimes B D - CA \otimes [D, B]$?

Comment: What's the smart way to represent the CNOT gate as a tensor product?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that $$\operatorname{CNOT}=\lvert0\rangle\!\langle0\rvert\otimes1+
\lvert1\rangle\!\langle1\rvert\otimes X.$$
Because $[1,\sigma]=0$ for any Pauli matrix $\sigma$, we immediately have
$$[\operatorname{CNOT},1\otimes\sigma]=\lvert1\rangle\!\langle1\rvert\otimes [X,\sigma],$$
which is consistent with your results noting that $\lvert1\rangle\!\langle1\rvert=(1-Z)/2$.

Furthermore, because
$\lvert0\rangle\!\langle0\rvert=(1+Z)/2$ and $\lvert1\rangle\!\langle1\rvert=(1-Z)/2,$
we see that
$$[\operatorname{CNOT},\sigma\otimes1]=\frac{1}{2}[Z,\sigma]\otimes(1-X).$$

The two expressions can be made to look even more similar by writing them as
\begin{align}
[\operatorname{CNOT},1\otimes\sigma]&=Z^-\otimes [X,\sigma],\\
[\operatorname{CNOT},\sigma\otimes1]&=[Z,\sigma]\otimes X^-,
\end{align}
where $\sigma^\pm\equiv(1\pm\sigma)/2$ are the projectors onto the $\pm$ eigenvectors of $\sigma$.